# setDisable for all fields of a Section in a Crm Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, disabled-input

I need to disable a section if a value from other field is true, normally I would do:

```
function disableSection1(disabledStatus){
    Xrm.Page.getControl("section1field1").setDisabled(disabledStatus);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("section1field2").setDisabled(disabledStatus);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("section1field3").setDisabled(disabledStatus);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("section1field4").setDisabled(disabledStatus);
}
```

but i have to do this for many sections, so I am looking for a function like this:

```
function sectionSetDisabled(tabNumber, sectionNumber, disabledStatus){
    //some code..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most answers I have seen you have use the use the sectionLable and do the following comparison:
`controlIHave.getParent().getLabel()=="name of the section`

But after some trials I found I could use `Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).sections.get(sectionNumber).controls.get()` to get the controls inside the section. That allowed me to use the following function:

```
function sectionSetDisabled(tabNumber, sectionNumber, disablestatus) {
    var section = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).sections.get(sectionNumber);
    var controls = section.controls.get();
    var controlsLenght = controls.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < controlsLenght; i++) {
        controls[i].setDisabled(disablestatus)
    }
}
```

by using `controls[i].getAttribute()` you can then get the attributes of a section.

I ended up creating a object that allows me to disable and clear all the fields in a section:

```
function sectionObject(tabNumber, sectionNumber) {
    var section = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).sections.get(sectionNumber);

    this.setDisabled = function (disablestatus) {
        var controls = section.controls.get();
        var controlsLenght = controls.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < controlsLenght; i++) {
            controls[i].setDisabled(disablestatus)
        }
    };

    this.clearFields = function () {
        var controls = section.controls.get();
        var controlsLenght = controls.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < controlsLenght; i++) {
            controls[i].getAttribute().setValue(null);
        }
    };

}

var section=new sectionObject(0,1);
section.setDisabled(true/false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function TabObject(tabName, DisableStatus) {  
         var sectionName = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabName).sections.get();
         for (var i in sectionName) {
         var controls = sectionName[i].controls.get();
         var controlsLenght = controls.length;
         for (var i = 0; i < controlsLenght; i++) {
             controls[i].setDisabled(DisableStatus);
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In CRM 2013 (and later), you can use the [`forEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481592.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_forEach) iterator. This essentially allows the functionality in a one-liner.

```
/* Parameters:
 * tabNumber = Tab Name/Id assigned in the form editor.
 * sectionNumber = Section Name/Id assigned in the form editor.
 */

function sectionSetDisabled(tabNumber, sectionNumber, disabledStatus) {
    // Pull the tab, then section (within the tab) and create an iterator.
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).sections.get(sectionNumber).controls.forEach(
        // Delegate to set the status of all controls within the section.
        function (control, index) {
            control.setDisabled(disabledStatus);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following article that provides code - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/09/29/disable-all-fields-in-a-section-based-on-the-value-of-another-field-crm-2011.aspx